# ggplot2 generating 2 legends. How to remove 1?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Trying to determine how to keep the colored legend and remove the greyscale one.
problem occured when I added the *labs(colour = "cover type") line.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsfSt.png)

```
nmds_plot_new <- ggplot(plot_df, aes(x = NMDS1, y = NMDS2)) +
  coord_fixed() +
  geom_point(aes(color = covertype, shape = covertype), size = 3, alpha = 0.8) +
  stat_ellipse(aes(color = covertype)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = pal) +
  geom_segment(data = fit_spp, aes(x = 0, xend = NMDS1, y = 0, yend = NMDS2),
           arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.25, "cm")),
           col = "black") +
  geom_text(data = fit_spp, aes(label = species), family="serif") +
  labs(title = "NMDS") + labs(colour = "Cover Type") +
  theme(text = element_text(family = "serif")) +
  clean_background
```

Tried finding a solution elsewhere but came up short.

Comment: Try giving them both the same title `labs(colour = "Cover Type", shape = "Cover Type")`. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.